# Import Errors while deploying Django project

Tags: python, django, shell

I am deploying a django project for the first time and am having some difficulties. Firstly, when following the django installation instructions on the web server I am using they instruct you to input the following command into the shell:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/USERNAME/public_html/lib/python
```

If I do not run this command I get a import error for django.core.management. It is annoying to have to enter this in every time I log into the shell! I have tried adding

```
*manage.py*    
sys.path.append('/home/USERNAME/public_html/lib/python')
```

but this doesnt work and I still have to run the export command every time I log into shell.

My second issue is I am also getting an import error for the site packages my project is using. Using

```
$  pip list
```

It showes all the packages are correctly installed.

So in conclusion, I am getting an import error for django.core.management everytime I log into shell. Then I will enter

```
 export PYTHONPATH=/home/USERNAME/public_html/lib/python
```

and my first error goes away. But after that I get import errors for every site package i try to use even though they are correctly installed.

Any advice on how to correct these issues?

Comment: Can you paste the exact traceback here

Comment: go to your main projects directory and type this ./manage.py shell

Comment: Are you using a Virtual Environment? How is your project being deployed? Link to the tutorial might help.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Then I will set the python path and get this: 
ImportError: No module named whoosh

Comment: here is the link to the tutorial: https://www.webhostpython.com/billing/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=56

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if this was the correct way but I did fix my problem. I just moved all of the installed packages onto the same path as

```
/home/USERNAME/public_html/lib/python
```

Now everything is up and running and working great.